# Shiny error while using nearPoints in renderPlotly click event

Tags: r, plotly, shiny, ropensci

I would like to fetch `nearPoints` using the data from a click event.

I have found the below snippet from the [Shiny webpage](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/plotOutput.html) and it works fine as expected.

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({
  d <- data()
  plot(d$speed, d$dist)
})

output$plot_clickedpoints <- renderPrint({
  # For base graphics, we need to specify columns, though for ggplot2,
  # it's usually not necessary.
  res <- nearPoints(data(), input$plot_click, "speed", "dist")
  if (nrow(res) == 0)
    return()
  res
})
```

I tried to mimic the above the approach to identify the `nearPoints` in the Plotly plots using the click event data. However, it did not work.

```
output$plot <- renderPlotly({
  d <- data()
  plot(d$speed, d$dist)
})

output$plot_clickedpoints <- renderPrint({
  # For base graphics, we need to specify columns, though for ggplot2,
  # it's usually not necessary.
  res <- nearPoints(data(), event_data("plotly_click"), "speed", "dist")
  if (nrow(res) == 0)
    return()
  res
})
```

Any idea on how to pass the coordinate information to the plotly plot?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure on how to do this with the nearPoints function, but is using that function really necessary? You could find the points that are within a threshold of the clicked point as well with the following code:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(DT)

threshold_mpg = 3
threshold_cyl = 1

shinyApp(

  ui <- shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
      plotlyOutput("plot"),
      DT::dataTableOutput("table")
    )
  ),
  function(input,output){

    data <- reactive({
      mtcars
    })

    output$plot <- renderPlotly({
      d <- data()
      plot_ly(d, x= ~mpg, y=~cyl, mode = "markers", type = "scatter", source="mysource")
    })

    output$table<- DT::renderDataTable({

      event.data <- event_data("plotly_click", source = "mysource")
      print(event.data)
      if(is.null(event.data)) { return(NULL)}

      # A simple alternative for the nearPoints function
      result <- data()[abs(data()$mpg-event.data$x)<=threshold_mpg & abs(data()$cyl-event.data$y)<=threshold_cyl, ]
      DT::datatable(result)
    })
  }
)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent suggestion @Florian. It works well when I select a point available on the plot. However, it does not work the same way when I click on the plot somewhere on the lines `cyl=5` or `cyl=7`.

Comment: @Prradep, I am afraid that solving that issue is outside of my capabilities, since I have limited knowledge of JavaScript. I initally thought to use a solution with plotly_hover and fetch the coordinates when clicked with shinyjs's onclick(), but plotly_hover has the same problem as plotly_click. I doubt it is even possible to fetch the coordinates from a random point in the plot, see [here](https://community.plot.ly/t/how-can-i-get-exact-x-y-pixel-coordinates-of-a-marker-point/3009). But this is more speculation from my part, there are others who can better address that issue (like Carson).

Comment: I agree with you. I have posted the question after going through the posts referred here. I will try with the speculative approach.

Answer (score 1):

The [`"plotly_selected"` plotly.js event](https://plot.ly/javascript/plotlyjs-events/#select-event) returns more information than `event_data("plotly_selected")` actually gives you, including coordinate information (this was arguably a design mistake made by `event_data()` that's too late to change). Fortunately, if you know a bit of JavaScript, know how to [listen to plotly select events](https://plot.ly/javascript/plotlyjs-events/#using-plotly.js-events), and how to [send data from client to a shiny server](https://ryouready.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/sending-data-from-client-to-server-and-back-using-shiny/), you can do something like this to access that info:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("p"),
  verbatimTextOutput("info")
)

server <- function(input, output, session, ...) {

  output$p <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(x = 1:10, y = 1:10) %>%
      layout(dragmode = "select") %>%
      onRender(
       "function(el, x) {
         var gd = document.getElementById(el.id);
         gd.on('plotly_selected', function(d) {
            // beware, sometimes this event fires objects that can't be seralized
            console.log(d);
            Shiny.onInputChange('my-select-event', d.range)
         })
       }")
  })


  output$info <- renderPrint({
    print(session$rootScope()$input[["my-select-event"]])
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Using the coordinate information you could write a function that works in a similar way to `nearPoints()`.